# How do I use 'Send' in Roblox's Private Messages Web API?

Tags: lua, roblox, luasocket

I've been here trying to send a message with luasocket and it had some problems, being `403: Token Validation Failed` and `401: Authorization has been denied for this request.`

```
local socket = require'socket.http'
local json = require'json'

print(os.date('at %c'..', the program starts.'))
-- bottom part is similar to http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2008-07/msg00206.html (not secure)

local result,code,headers,stats = socket.request(
    {
        method = 'POST',
        url = 'https://privatemessages.roblox.com/v1/messages/send',
        headers = ({
            ["Cookie"] =".ROBLOSECURITY=not-showing-to-you",
            ["content-length"]= 10 -- I have no idea how this thing works
        }
    }
)
print(json.encode(result))
print(code)
print(stats)
print(json.encode(headers))
```

## **EDIT**

I just gave up a few days after learning that its quite complicated without a wrapper thing idk.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see your problem is you put "Cookie" and it should be "cookie" also try removing the [] to see if that helps